# PHP filemtime function - "stat failed for"

Tags: php, unix, smarty

I have a problem with PHP filemtime function. In my webapp I use Smarty template engine with caching option. In my webapp I can do some actions which generate error, but lets focus on only one action. When I click link on page some content is updated - I can click few times and everything is OK but about one request on 10 fails. Following error occurs:

```
filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]: stat failed for
```

and the line that causes the problem:

```
 return ($_template->getCachedFilepath() && file_exists($_template->getCachedFilepath())) ? filemtime($_template->getCachedFilepath()) : false ;
```

As you can see, file exists because it is checked.

Problematic line of code is included in `smarty_internal_cacheresource_file.php` (part of Smarty lib v3.0.6)

App is run on UNIX system, external hosting.

Any ideas? Should I post more details?

Comment: Just a note: is the parent directory readable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`file_exists` internally uses the [`access`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/access.2.html) system call which checks permissions as the *real* user, whereas `filemtime` uses [`stat`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html), which performs the check as the *effective* user. Therefore, the problem may be rooted in the assumption of effective user == real user, which does not hold. Another explanation would be that the file gets deleted between the two calls.

Since both the result of `$_template->getCachedFilepath()` and the existance of the file can change in between system calls, why do you call `file_exists` at all? Instead, I'd suggest just

```
return @filemtime($_template->getCachedFilepath());
```

If `$_template->getCachedFilepath()` can be set to a dummy value such as `false`, use the following:

```
$path = $_template->getCachedFilepath();
if (!$path) return false;
return @filemtime($path);
```

Comment: I understand that file can disappear between two calls, but I am only one who tests this application. I also test it only for one user thats why it is strange for me. I can ignore error by putting @ sign, but the problem will not disappear.

Comment: I don't like solutions that include error suppression, but +1 for the effective/real note. @marchewa check the permissions of the files.

Comment: Permissions of all cached files are 0644 (rw-r--r--). My scripts create, deletes and try to read these files. As I said only about 10% of requests fail.

Comment: @Darhazer What's wrong with error suppression if errors are expected? It's definitely better than look-before-you-leap unless you can guarantee the state won't change.

Comment: @marchewa If the problem only occurs intermittently, it could very well be that the temporary file is removed after you call `file_exists`, but before `filemtime`. Can you reproduce the problem with two calls to `filemtime`, i.e. using `(@filemtime(..) !== false)` instead of `file_exists`?

Comment: @phihah I've done what you suggested and right now first call of `filemtime` always emits `E_WARNING`. I suppose you are right from the begining. Earlier in my script I call `clearCache` Smarty function which uses `unlink` function to delete file. When I comment out this line problem disappears, otherwise problem randomly occures. Question is: is it possible that file is physically deleted after some time of calling `unlink` function?

Comment: @marchewa No, if the same process(and thread) issues an `unlink` and then a `filemtime` call, the file will not be there. Bear in mind multiple concurrent processes are the rule, not the exception on a webserver. You should go with my original answer - just cal `filemtime` once, and put an `@` in front to suppress the warning.

Comment: ok, thanks I will do that. I will also post change request to the Smarty developers.

Comment: _Smarty 3.1 should already solve the issue_   http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=19689&sid=60e6e3293aed78bc712066f03b22f88b

Comment: How does one display who is the effective and real user? For debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Smarty::muteExpectedErrors();
```

Read [this](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/troubleshooting.tpl) and [this](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.mute.expected.errors.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

I used filemtime successfully without checking "file_exists" for years.  The way I have always interpreted the documentation is that FALSE should be returned from "filemtime" upon any error.  Then a few days ago something very weird occurred.  If the file did not exist, my Cron job terminated with a result.  The result was not in the program output but rather in the Cron output.  The message was "file length exceeded".  I knew the Cron job ended on the filemtime statement because I sent myself an email before and after that statement.  The "after" email never arrived.

I inserted a file_exists check on the file to fix the Cron job.  However, that should not have been necessary.  I still do not know what was changed on the hosting server I use.  Several other Cron jobs started failing on the same day.  I do not know yet whether they have anything to do with filemtime.