# Php and Smarty3 - filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for

Tags: exception, error-handling, smarty, smarty3

I'm migrating my WebAPP from Smarty2 to Smarty3. Every step is easy except one. When i display  a Smarty Template ( tpl ) an Exception is thrown.

This line

`Source: /path_to_file/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_resource.php (773)`

(this is the source coude `$compiled->timestamp = @filemtime($compiled->filepath);` )

raise this Exception **when the file doesn't exists**

`filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for /path_to_templates/smarty/templates_c/219dfe732aae7bd7c0edab091e3c53f3ce86b058.file.index.tpl.php`

**Folder permissions**:

Smarty template folder Permission : **775**

Smarty Cache folder permission: **775**

**Folder Owners**:

both *ftp_user:webserver_user*

I'm trying to implement different solutions but it seems not possibile to solve this issue whitout changhing **Php Error Reporting** or disabling my **Error Handler** .

How can i solve this problem without hacks ?

Comment: Have you cleaned `templates_c` and `cache` directory after changing version?

Comment: yes, i do. It seems a Smarty 3.1.16 Bug. Switching to Smarty 3.1.1 the bug doesn't appear anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is not to downgrade to 3.1.1 but rather try to upgrade to `3.1.19` version. Many bugs are removed all the time so maybe in this version you won't have it.

The other thing is that you can use [muteExpectedErrors](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.mute.expected.errors.tpl) method to hide file system warnings from Smarty (documentation for this function is not very clear but it affects file system warnings what is explained in error_reporting documentation). You can read at [error_reporting documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.error.reporting.tpl) page:

> Smarty 3.1.2 introduced the muteExpectedErrors() function. Calling
>   Smarty::muteExpectedErrors(); after setting up custom error handling
>   will ensure that warnings and notices (deliberately) produced by
>   Smarty will not be passed to other custom error handlers. If your
>   error logs are filling up with warnings regarding filemtime() or
>   unlink() calls, please enable Smarty's error muting.

Comment: I've upgraded my working Copy with the 3.1.19 (**Download of Smarty-3-1-19.zip**) and the bug still raising. So, i've downloaded the **Smarty-stable.zip** , [_marked as 3.1.19_](http://www.smarty.net/download) , and i noticed that inside the zip there is the Smarty **3.1.18** version, not the 3.1.19. I will test this version ASAP !!!!

Comment: Accoring to Smarty administrators, you should simple mute those error as I said and don't worry about them at all.

Comment: @alesdario And one more thing. You may get this notice because file simple doesn't exists. It's quite possible that some optimization were made and simple `if file_exists` was removed.  You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7120844/3593996

Comment: muteExpectedErrors() seems working fine but it mute also warning errors like _wrong parameters count_ errors (Ex `var_dump()` without parameters should thrown a warning) . Can i modify mute error level?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't affect it at all. Assume I have in my tpl `{$x|var_dump}` and variable 'x' hasn't been set in Smarty. When I use `$smarty->muteExpectedErrors();` I get 2 notices. When I want to hide them, I need to use also `$smarty->error_reporting = 0;` so for me `muteExpectedErrors` doesn't affect other warnings

Answer (score 0):

Check the filesystem permission on /path_to_templates/smarty/templates_c/219dfe732aae7bd7c0edab091e3c53f3ce86b058.file.index.tpl.php

PHP does not seam to have read/write permission on that file.

Also check the permission in the /path_to_templates/smarty/templates_c/ folder. Is the PHP allowed to read list and write in there as well?

Comment: Which user/group does the templates_c folder belong to? And which user/group is PHP running under? Because, if it differs, the 775 won't be enough and 777 is needed.

Comment: both ftp_user:webserver_user